# Cannot compile code with clang, but works with gcc

Tags: c++, xcode, clang++

I am trying to fix some bugs in an open source C++ project and the original author is currently too busy with his academic life to help. The code compiles just fine with `gcc-4.9` installed via macports. And I have been debugging with `lldb` on the command line. However, if possible, I would like to get the code to compile with `clang` since that would let me use Xcode and `lldb` together and make the bug easier to isolate.

When I try to compile the code with `clang`, I get the following error:

```
In file included from ./src/include/hash.h:25:
./src/include/hash_stream.h:18:11: error: call to function 'operator>>' that is neither visible in the template definition
  nor found by argument-dependent lookup
  iss >> table[key] ;
      ^
./src/common/tagger/implementations/collins/tagger.h:118:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
  'operator>><CWord, english::CTag>' requested here
  i >> (*m_TopTags);
    ^
./src/english/tags.h:29:23: note: 'operator>>' should be declared prior to the call site or in namespace 'english'
inline std::istream & operator >> (std::istream &is, english::CTag &tag) {
                  ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/english.postagger.o] Error 1
```

This error occurs in [this](https://github.com/desilinguist/zpar/blob/master/src/include/hash_stream.h) file which is basically trying to read a key, a `:`, and a value separated by spaces into a custom hash map. I have read the relevant [section](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#dep_lookup) in the clang compatibility guide but I cannot figure out what I need to change to get this to compile.

**EDIT**: Per @m-s, I modified `src/common/tagger/implementations/collins/tagger_include.h` to move `tags.h` above `hash_stream.h` and that seemed to fix that error. However, I now run into a new error:

```
In file included from ./src/common/conparser/implementations/muhua/weight.cpp:13:
In file included from ./src/common/conparser/implementations/muhua/weight.h:13:
In file included from ./src/common/conparser/weight_base.h:13:
In file included from ./src/common/conparser/base_include.h:10:
In file included from ./src/english/tags.h:43:
In file included from ./src/english/pos/penn_morph.h:15:
In file included from ./src/include/knowledge/tagdict.h:15:
In file included from ./src/include/hash.h:25:
./src/include/hash_stream.h:15:11: error: call to function 'operator>>' that is neither visible in the template definition
      nor found by argument-dependent lookup
      iss >> key;
          ^
./src/include/learning/perceptron/hashmap_score_packed.h:282:7: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'operator>><std::__1::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long>, CPackedScore<double, 2048> >' requested here
   is >> static_cast< CHashMap< K, CPackedScore<SCORE_TYPE, PACKED_SIZE> > &>(score_map) ;
      ^
./src/common/conparser/implementations/muhua/weight.cpp:48:27: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'operator>><std::__1::pair<unsigned long, unsigned long>, double, 2048>' requested here
   iterate_templates(file >>,;);
                          ^
./src/common/conparser/implementations/muhua/weight.h:133:4: note: expanded from macro 'iterate_templates'
   left(m_mapS0cmN0tm)right\
   ^
./src/include/pair_stream.h:16:16: note: 'operator>>' should be declared prior to the call site
std::istream & operator >> (std::istream &is, std::pair<T1, T2> &p) {
               ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/english.conparser/weight.o] Error 1
```

I tried to include `pair_stream.h` before `hash.h` but that doesn't seem to work and I am stumped again. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT 2**: I actually thought about things and took another stab at this and now it all works. Thanks, everyone! StackOverflow is awesome :)

Comment: Your next step is to reduce your code to the smallest possible example that displays the problem, then add that code and the error messages it generates your question.  For more about this see this help page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Since I am fairly unfamiliar with the large-ish code base, trying to come up with an MCVE is quite challenging for me. However, I will try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message states, `std::istream & operator >> (std::istream &is, english::CTag &tag)` is defined in `src/english/tags.h`. 
But since the template in `src/include/hash_stream.h` which calls it is declared before that file is included, the error occurs.

The documentation already provides the solution:

> Make sure the function you want to call is declared before the template that might call it. This is the only option if none of its argument types contain classes. You can do this either by moving the template definition, or by moving the function definition, or by adding a forward declaration of the function before the template.

So either make sure this file is included **before** including `src/include/hash_stream.h`, or apply any of the solutions provided by the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to help but now I run into a new error that I cannot seem to fix in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

`operator>>` is defined for `istringstream`. Try to include `#include <sstream>` file in your source before wherever `namespace english` is defined.

Comment: operator >> is defined in a lot of places for a lot of different objects.  Do you know that he is using a stringstream?  It could be he needs to include <istream> or <iostream> or ...    We need more information.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases if you can't just change order of declarations to avoid the problem - you can do **forward declaration**.